# How to handle orientation delegate method in IOS6, IOS7 and IOS 8?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, orientation, autorotate

I am working on the new iphone app and I have to give orientation support in all IOS version(ios 6 and later). can anybody explain what is the best way to handle orientation for all IOS versions.

I searched and found that few of older version delegate methods have been deprecated in the newer version of IOS.

How should I manage of this?
Please provide idea.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS7 & iOS8 you can use auto layout and size classes when you create a new project a 
600x600 resolution ViewController is added you have to add constraints on that ViewController then it will run same on all devices

For auto layout you can follow these tutorials

```
1-[http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial][1]
2-[http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/][2]
3-[http://www.brianjcoleman.com/autolayout-xcode6/][3]
Even it will run on iPads too.
```

thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think those three methods can meet your requirement.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
```

Comment: Yes, they will work (iOS6 and later) so far, because NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0)